# Auto Updating Tableview in JAVA Fx

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8

In my project when a client will be disconnected, server will delete the name from observable list and the tableview should stop showing the name. But the tableview is not updating.
Controller class

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
public TableView tableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<clientLoginData,String> client;
@FXML
private TableColumn<clientLoginData,String> activeTime;
void initialize(ObservableList<clientLoginData> data)
{
    client.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("clientName"));
    client.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<clientLoginData>forTableColumn());
    activeTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("time"));
    activeTime.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<clientLoginData>forTableColumn());
    tableView.setItems(data);
    tableView.setEditable(true);

}

}
```

main class

```
public class Main extends Application{
volatile public  ObservableList<clientLoginData> data= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
public Controller controller;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("server.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    data.addAll(new clientLoginData((new SimpleStringProperty("john")),new SimpleStringProperty(ZonedDateTime.now().getHour()+":"+ZonedDateTime.now().getMinute())));
    controller=loader.getController();
    controller.initialize(data);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Server");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
    Thread t=new Thread(new messengerServer(this));
    t.start();



}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

updating class

```
public class messengerReadThread implements Runnable {
private Thread thr;
private NetworkUtil nc;
public Hashtable<SimpleStringProperty, NetworkUtil> table;
SimpleStringProperty  oldName;
Main main;


public messengerReadThread(NetworkUtil nc, Hashtable<SimpleStringProperty, NetworkUtil> table, SimpleStringProperty s, Main main) {
    this.nc = nc;
    this.thr = new Thread(this);
    thr.start();
    this.table=table;
    oldName=s;
    this.main=main;
}

public void run() {

    try {
        while(true) {
            String s1=(String)nc.read();
            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s1);
            if(st.nextToken().equals("Name"))
            {
                String sn=s1.substring(5,s1.length());
                NetworkUtil n1=table.get(oldName);
                table.remove(oldName);
                oldName=new SimpleStringProperty(sn);
                table.put(oldName, n1);
                main.data.add(new clientLoginData(oldName,new SimpleStringProperty(ZonedDateTime.now().getHour()+":"+ZonedDateTime.now().getMinute())));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("here it is"+s1);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("disconnected "+oldName.toString());
        main.data.remove(oldName);
        //System.out.println(main.data.contains(oldName));

        main.controller.tableView.refresh();//the tableview should update

    }
    nc.closeConnection();
}
}
```

Comment: Your main.data.remove call will never have any effect, since you're trying to remove a StringProperty from a `List<clientLoginData>`.  Also, all modifications of observable objects need to be done on the application thread.  This means `main.data.add` and `main.data.remove` must be invoked inside [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some modification I should to to that code, like avoid using those "static references", by defining the ObservableList and move your Updating Code inside Controller so you can have a 2 classes code, the Main Class and your Controller... but i'll try to keep it simple.

First, you need to define the ObservableList inside you controller.

Then place your "updating" code inside the controller in a method. I suggest you to use a Task<> to keep your controller updated in the JavaFX Thread.

Try something like this:

```
private void updateTable(){ 

    Task<Void> myUpdatingTask=new Task<Void>() {
       @Override
       protected Void call() throws Exception {
        //Your Updating Code Here
       }
    }

    //and then you run it like this:
    Thread hilo=new Thread(myUpdatingTask);
    hilo.setDaemon(true);
    hilo.start();
}
```

Then, remove the parameter from your Initialize Method and define it private with the @FXML annotation like this:

```
@FXML
private void initialize(){
     //Your Stuff to initialize
     //here is were you fill your table like you did in the Main
     //and don't forget to call you updateTable Method
     this.updateTable();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since this a dirty hack as pointed out by @kleopatra I am going to decorate it as a dirty hack.
****************************Dirty Hack*****************************************
Try hiding a column and displaying it again and your tableview should refresh

Comment: no need for dirty hacks: provided all collaborators are wired correctly, the update will happen automagically

Comment: @kleopatra I have been talking to oracle about that, table view also causes memory leaks. They have not yet fixed that. Unless there is an event associated with I have not been able to update the table without dirty hacks. event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()).setSomething(event.getNewValue().trim());

Comment: Come to think of that you could possibly generate your own event to update the table.

Comment: in 99.999 % of tableView not updating on changing the data, there's something wrong with the data setup. For the rest, there's  `tableView.refresh()`

Comment: @kleopatra we followed the implementation as oracle described it in it's examples. It did not work for us 99.99% of the time. tableview.refresh() did not do anything for us. There were bugs submitted and accepted by oracle at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/. There was post on stack overflow that it has been fixed in update 60

Comment: @kleopatra you should consider posting an example of data is setup in tableview to prove your point